# Assign event number based on change location or Date in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

In data frame `evdf` how to assign number such that it increases *either by 1 after every zero* in `ev` column **or** when there is a *change/gap in the date* (`Date`) column. i.e., I want to create a column like `outevdf` in `outevdf`.
It may be too simple but could not figure out :(.

```
evdf<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(16598, 16599, 16600, 16601, 
16602, 16603, 16604, 16605, 16606, 16607, 16610, 16611, 16612, 
16613, 16614, 16615, 16616, 16617, 16618, 16619, 16620, 16621, 
16622, 16623, 16624, 16631, 16632, 16633), class = "Date"), ev = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
evdf
```

Expected output

```
outevdf<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(16598, 16599, 16600, 16601, 
16602, 16603, 16604, 16605, 16606, 16607, 16610, 16611, 16612, 
16613, 16614, 16615, 16616, 16617, 16618, 16619, 16620, 16621, 
16622, 16623, 16624, 16631, 16632, 16633), class = "Date"), ev = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), outevdf = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-28L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), ev = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), outevdf = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

outevdf
```

Follwoing  @badalovi answer,  when i implement in larger dataset, the increment is not continuous. See

```
evdf2 <-structure(list(Date = structure(c(16191, 16192, 16193, 16194, 
16195, 16201, 16202, 16203, 16204, 16205, 16206, 16207, 16208, 
16211, 16212, 16213, 16214, 16215, 16216, 16217, 16218, 16219, 
16220, 16221, 16222, 16223, 16224, 16225, 16226, 16227, 16228, 
16229, 16230, 16231, 16232, 16233, 16234, 16235, 16236, 16237, 
16238, 16239, 16240, 16241, 16242, 16243, 16244, 16245, 16246, 
16247, 16248, 16249, 16250, 16252, 16253, 16254, 16255, 16256, 
16257, 16258, 16259, 16260, 16261, 16262, 16263, 16264, 16265, 
16266, 16267, 16268, 16269, 16270, 16271, 16274, 16275, 16276, 
16277, 16278, 16279, 16280, 16281, 16282, 16283, 16284, 16285, 
16286, 16287, 16293, 16294, 16295, 16296, 16297, 16298, 16299, 
16300, 16301, 16302, 16303, 16304, 16305, 16306, 16307, 16308, 
16309, 16310, 16311, 16312, 16313, 16314, 16315, 16316, 16317, 
16318, 16319, 16320, 16321, 16322, 16323, 16324, 16325, 16326, 
16327, 16328, 16331, 16332, 16333, 16334, 16335, 16336, 16337, 
16338, 16339, 16340, 16341, 16342), class = "Date"), ev = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), outev = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15)), row.names = c(NA, 
-135L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This example should solve your problem.

```
evdf$outev <- evdf$ev+ cumsum(evdf$ev==0)
```

Edit:

```
evdf$outev <- evdf$ev+ cumsum(evdf$ev==0)+cumsum(c(0,ifelse(diff.Date(evdf$Date)==1,0,1)))
```

Comment: I added new solution to your question. If it is what you are looking for you can click the tick to chose it as answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much @badalovi, however, when I used it in my real data, the increment is not continuous. For example, in the sample `evdf2` (edited in question) there is not event `3` but `4` after 2.  Can you have a look at why it may be so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum` :

```
evdf$event <- c(1, head(cumsum(!evdf$ev), -1) + 1)
```

---

and with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
evdf %>% mutate(event = lag(cumsum(!ev) + 1, default = 1))

#A tibble: 29 x 2
#      ev event
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     1
# 3     1     1
# 4     1     1
# 5     0     1
# 6     1     2
# 7     1     2
# 8     1     2
# 9     1     2
#10     1     2
# … with 19 more rows
```

For the updated data we can use :

```
evdf2 %>% 
  mutate(event = cumsum(!ev | Date - lag(Date, default = first(Date)) > 1) + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks but the new event start after `0`, not at `0` like in your solution, please see `outevdf` for what I am expecting. Yes, there are only 1 and 0.

Comment: @LilyNature Updated the answer to get expected output.

Comment: Thanks, can  you have a look at the slightly modified question (as edited above), please

Comment: @LilyNature Can you check if the updated answer helps you?

Comment: thank you, it still did not quite work. The new event should start after `0` not at `0`, so in the solution, it would be fine if event `3` comes after `0` i.e., start at `2014-05-21` and continue until `2014-05-28` while event `4` starts from `2014-05-29` and so on.

Comment: But there is also difference of dates from `2014-05-18` to `2014-05-21`. Shouldn't that be counted as well then?

Comment: Yes, the date gap should be counted but not independently. Until 0 is the previous event. There are total 3 conditions, date gap = start of a new event, 0 in ev column, the start of the new event after zero, date gap and 0 (like in this), again new event after 0. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A modification as below to @badalovi's answer will provide the desired answer to the question.

```
evdf$outev <- evdf$ev+ cumsum(evdf$ev==0)+cumsum(c(0,ifelse(diff.Date(evdf$Date)==1,0,1)))
evdf$outev1<-c(1,diff(evdf$outev))
i<-which(evdf$outev1!=0)
evdf$outev1[i] <- 1:length(i)
evdf$outev2<-ifelse(evdf$outev1==0,NA,evdf$outev1)
evdf<-evdf%>%
  fill(outev2)
```

Comment: Great to see you reached the solution !